# shared only with developers and testers while this application being built

Tags: android, facebook

i already use facebook sdk to make post and it is done but the post not seen by the public 
and this is the massage that i get from my facebook wall

"shared only with developers and testers while this application being built"

, can any one help me and explain how to make it show to everyone not only developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In facebook on your app settings page, disable the sandbox mode.